# Как отображаются в документе узлы, у которых объект-прототип - TEXT?

Tags: html, css

Привет.

Вопрос по хтмл. Когда пишется разметка, то используются символы форматирования - пробел, табуляция, перевод строки. Потом из этих символов форматирования получаются объекты узлы с прототипом `TEXT`. Эти объекты-узлы не являются блочными или строчными элементами, так как это *не лежащий в элементе текст*, но они как-то отображаются. Вопрос - **как отображаются эти узлы**? Эти узлы не являются элементами, поэтому к ним неприменимо понятие "блочный элемент" и "строчный элемент". **Как рассчитывается ширина текстового узла?** Вообще об этом ни слова не встречал.

Перед тем, как отобразить, браузер строит макет страницы. При макетировании браузер вычисляет размеры и положение всего на странице перед тем, как расположить. вот меня как раз и заинтересовало, как браузер считает размеры и положение строковых узлов.

Вот пример:

```
<style>
            span{
                display:inline-block;
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
                background-color:red;
            }
 </style>

<div>
            <span>qwe</span>
            <span>asd</span>
            <span>zxc</span>
</div>
```

Получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Маргины спанам я не задавал.

Эту фигню можно победить тремя способами:

1. писать в одну строку без пробелов и энтэров.
2. удалить узлы текстовые джаваскриптом.
3. задать диву-контейнеру font-size:0px, а спану - нужный font-size, например 12px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При рендере html - браузеры учитывают пробелы, переводы строк и табуляции, сворачивая их до одиночного пробела, который вы и видите в результате. Зазор между блоками как раз выходит шириной в одиночный пробел.

По этой же причине, если указать для контейнера `font-size: 0;` - ширина любых символов (и пробелов) будет равна нулю. И зазоров уже не будет.

Answer (score 2):

У вас родительский div имеет font-size. И из-за этого получается проблема. Поставивьте родительскому диву font-size: 0 а дочерним задайте свой  font-size